# Jsoup extracting child of a div

Tags: java, jsoup, extract, element

I'm trying to extract the link for some ads on an website but i can't manage to make it work:( The div looks like this:
[image]

I can't extract it by using the a href class id because other links have different classes which made me try to extract it by using the h3 class id which is the same for every add but i can't get it to work or i'm surely doing something wrong.

```
Elements pageSearch3 = page2.select(".lheight22.margintop5");
                for(int l = 0; l < pageSearch3.size(); l++) {
                    String url = pageSearch3.get(l).attr("href");
                    System.out.println(url);
                }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.lheight22.margintop5` this be `.lheight22.margintop5 > a`? You are selecting `h3` rather than `a`.

Comment: I've tried like that and it still gives me the text from h3 not the link :(

Comment: Can you print the tag_name and check that you are getting `a`?

Comment: sorry i forgot the .attr() method:( Now it works fine! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look of the selector documentation https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax .

> parent > child: child elements that descend directly from parent, e.g.
>   div.content > p finds p elements; and body > * finds the direct
>   children of the body tag